# Compromised server with psyBNC - what are our next steps?

Tags: malware, privacy, exploit, attack-prevention, incident-response

One of our VPS servers has an install of [psybnc](http://www.microsoft.com/security/portal/threat/encyclopedia/entry.aspx?Name=Backdoor%3aWin32/Psybnc.A&ThreatID=-2147476261) on it. The install has been present for quite some time, and has now been brought to our attention. We have backups, but they also have psybnc on them. What would be our next steps, and what what could the potential impact be of having psybnc installed?

I personally do not have access to the servers in question, but have been asked to provide input on the situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PsyBNC](http://www.psybnc.at/about.html) is an [IRC bouncer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BNC_%28software%29), i.e. a program meant to relay communications for the [IRC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Relay_Chat) chat network. By itself, it is pretty benign; it uses part of your CPU and bandwidth, and might be used as an indirect tool for relaying data or mounting attacks of questionable legality.

The **real question** is: since installing and launching this program requires administrative rights on your server, whoever did it could have done a lot more things. So, what did he do ?

The *potential* impact is that this unidentified individual installed other tools, e.g. a [rootkit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rootkit), meaning that he can come back at will and totally control the machine; no data on it is safe, and the machine can then be used in various nefarious schemes which could be very embarrassing for you (up to and including plunging you into deep legal trouble -- in a kind-of worst case scenario where the attacker is part of Al-Qaida and brings your machine to the attention of the CIA). As a basic rule, if your machine is rootkitted, then it no longer is *your* machine.

Therefore, the **prudent course** is to reformat the machine and resinstall it from scratch. All your backups are suspect, too.

*Nuke, nuke, nuke from orbit*
*Cleanse it with fire*
*Kill, kill, kill all the bits*
*Lest things become dire*

Comment: I appreciate the advise - it's essentially mirrored what myself and my co-worker has been telling our management staff. I will be sure to reiterate the importance. Thanks again.